# Form validation is not working in MEAN Stack using angular js and node js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

Hello I am working with MEAN Stack application.When I add record data stored

Successfully. But When I don't fill any field and click add button which is

Calling function for store record My function working properly But I used the

**Validation field is required** but function working and redirect my given path.

new data is not storing but why function is working.

function in controller

```
 $scope.adduser = function() 
    {

        $http({
            method:"POST",
            url:'api/adduser',
            data:{name:$scope.name, email:$scope.email,password:$scope.password}
             }).then(function successCallback(response) {
              if(response.data.error){
                    $scope.error = response.data.error;

              }else{

                    $scope.Blog=response.data;
                    $localStorage.dd=$scope.Blog;
                    $location.path('/allusers');
              }
              //console.log(response);
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
               alert("data is not comming here");
            });


    }
```

message show field is required but not stay there go to the given path when

response success. how to resolved this problem

view file is

```
<!-- BEGIN PAGE HEADER-->
<h3 class="page-title">
    Advanced Datatables <small>advanced datatable samples</small>
</h3>
<div class="page-bar">
    <ul class="page-breadcrumb">
        <li>
            <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#/allusers">All Users</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <!-- BEGIN VALIDATION STATES-->
        <div class="portlet box blue-hoki">
            <div class="portlet-title">
                <div class="caption">
                    <i class="fa fa-gift"></i>
                   New User
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="portlet-body form">

                <form id = "expensesCreate" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-body">
                        <div class="alert alert-danger display-hide">
                            <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
                            You have some form errors. Please check below.
                        </div>


                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">

                            <label for="price" class="col-sm-3">Name</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4 @if($errors->has('price')) has-error @endif">
                                <input class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" id="first_name"  name="name" ng-model="name" type="text" value ="" required>
                                <p class="error"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">

                            <label for="price" class="col-sm-3">Email</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4 @if($errors->has('price')) has-error @endif">
                                <input class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" id="email" name="email" ng-model="email" type="text" value ="" required>
                                <p class="error"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Phone_no" class="col-sm-3">Password</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4 @if($errors->has('Phone_no')) has-error @endif">
                                <input class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" id="phone_no"  name="company_name" ng-model="password"  type="text" value ="" required>
                                <p class="error"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                     <div class="form-actions">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">

                                <button  ng-click="adduser()" class="btn blue-hoki">Add</button>
                                <a ng-href="#/allusers">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn default" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
                                </a>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    </div>

                </form>
                <!-- END FORM-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END VALIDATION STATES-->
    </div>
</div>
<style>

.form-horizontal .form-group {
    margin-right: -15px;
   margin-left: 0px;
}


</style>
```

Comment: where have you sued 'validation field is required' ?

Comment: are you setting response.data.error to true from your server, whenver the input is not valid ?

Comment: @gaurav5430 I given field required input type in view file

Comment: please provide your view code as well

Comment: I edited my question and I want  front side validation

Comment: you haven't provided any error messages in <p class="error"> , also you would need to disable the button until all fields are valid, if you are going to allow to click 'Add' , it will call adduser(), even if the fields are valid or not

Comment: How to apply this type of validation

Comment: read more about angular form validation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131158/discussion-between-shahzad-ditro-and-gaurav5430).

Answer (score 1):

Add disabled attribute on your button validation while the form is invalid

```
<button  ng-click="adduser()" class="btn blue-hoki" ng-disabled="expensesCreate.$invalid">Add</button>
```

Comment: i applied validation of angular js and this is working to  add user but I applied same validation edit the record it is not working.